# How to toggle the boolean status?

Tags: c#, boolean

Is this the way to toggle the boolean for mode?

```
_mode = false;

public bool Turn()
{
return _mode = !_mode
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as putting

> `_mode = true;`